# Copy/Paste Sumif formula in google sheets

Tags: excel, sumifs

I have a sumif formula in google sheets that looks like this:

> =30-(SUMIF('Formulas for point transfer'!$A$2:$A$20,B2,'Formulas for point transfer'!$E$2:$E$20))+(SUMIF('Formulas for point transfer'!$B$2:$B$20,B2,'Formulas for point transfer'!$E$2:$E$20))

It is to be used to calculate point transfers for babysitting swap hours.  I start out with 30 points, then if my name appears in column A, points from column E will be subtracted...if my name appears in column B, points from column E will be added.  This formula is working on the first row of data.  But when I copy/paste it to the rows beneath, it no longer functions.  I am keeping everything the same except for the search criteria (instead of searching for the text in B2 from the original formula, I changed it to search for text in B3, B4, B5, etc...for each new row of data) What am I doing wrong?

A little more background info:
The data is originating from a google form that members fill out.  The results are loaded into a tab on my google sheet document. I have then created a new tab with an array formula to transfer the results from the form into a new sheet where I can add in the formulas I need.  I can't add the formulas to the original results page because each new form entry creates a new row and the formulas are not automatically copied into that new row. Perhaps there is an easier way to do this but I'm not experienced enough to know how.  Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I can't see any issue with your formula, if it works with first row it should work in the others too. Are you sure names in next rows are correct? Try to copy B2 to B3

Comment: Yes, the names are automatically entered from the google form so there is no possibility of typos.  I can't figure out what could be happening between the first row and the subsequent rows that is making a difference.

Comment: I also tried changing the search criteria in the first row formula to say B3 instead of B2 to see if it would work on that row and it did not work.  The only search criteria that is currently working is if it searches for the text in B2.  Any ideas?